# Android: how to have Horizontal-List-View with different width-size items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, horizontallist

I have a horizontal-listView in my layout.

In my horizontal-listView's item-layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPic"

    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

which show image perfectly. when I set imageView's height & width to:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="170dp"
```

it doesn't "show" the images (images are there when I click on their empty place) which are loaded from url and are in different size.

and it seems only horizontal-listView list view have this problem and regular listView is OK with this.

can anybody help me through this?

**EDIT:**
my horizontal-listView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f9f9f9"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/info.pics"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--horizontal list-view for Apk-Pics-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <appstore.pishtaz.com.appstore.utils.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/hlvApkPics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

now, its like [this](http://jalaldoth.persiangig.com/image/Capture.PNG), but I need it to be like [this](http://jalaldoth.persiangig.com/image/Capture2.PNG).

Comment: try sacleType as centerCrop in imageview.

Comment: could you add the xml of your ListView?

Comment: @Harry: I tried "centerCrop" before. it crop image(when width != height) and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've got no clue. Is there anything special about the listView you implemented? If not, I would suggest to take a look at RecyclerView using a horizontal LinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the image library [Picasso?](http://square.github.io/picasso/) It will help you easily deal with image resizing, caching of the images (improved performance, better user experience)

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
.into(imageView);
```

Picasso will also help you resize and recrop the image by adding:

```
.resize(50, 50)
.centerCrop();
```

It's an extremely simple library to use, and it will help you with all your image-related needs down the road.

Comment: I don't wanna re-size images. they are already in different size.  I load them into my horizontal-list-view. I just need to represent them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Get the width of your imageView, then set its height by a ratio

example:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,width*3/4);
yourImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```